# Use VBA to hide/unhide columns (named ranges) in a table based on selection made in a separate cell on a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a selection criteria cell on Sheet1 and have a table on Sheet 2. Sheet 1 Cell B3 will have a dropdown with different options. I want to be able to make a selection in this dropdown which will accordingly hide/unhide certain columns in the table on Sheet2. So far the code i have below is based on selections being made on the same sheet as the table and i'm stuck as the code isnt working as i expect it to.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 3 And Target.Value = "CustomView" Then

Range("Fruits", "Months").Select

Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Else

Range("Fruits", "Months").Select


Application.Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End If

End Sub
```

The named ranges i specified using the formulas section. "Months" is in column G, and "Fruits" is in column I, yet the code currently hides columns G, H and I, instead of just column G and column I. Furthermore, everytime i try to move the selection criteria to a separate sheet, i get errors. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range selection is incorrect.  Instead of `Range("Fruits", "Months").Select` you need to instead do `Range("Fruits, Months").Select`

Comment: Thanks @tigervatar - that fixes my issue with the columns not hiding as required.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a re-write that will help you simplify the readability and maintainability of this code moving forward.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then 
        Range("Fruits,Months").EntireColumn.Hidden = Target.Value = "CustomView"
    End If

End Sub
```

To be clear, this should not be marked as answer, because tigeravatar already fixed your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Scott Holtzman, the code is much cleaner and intuitive as well now. One issue i was still facing was being able to make the code work by having the target.address cell on a separate sheet. is this possible?Not sure if i should be creating a seperate question - but basically i need the dropdown cells (currently in B3) to be on a different sheet and/or associated to a command button or checkbox as there are multiple different views to select from

Comment: @ThomasTcred - to move it on another sheet, you'd have to place the change code in that sheet and tie the ranges to hide to the sheet they are on. So, `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Fruits,Months").EntireColumn...`

Comment: Thanks @Scott that worked for me as well. appreciate your help!